# not able to generate controll flow graphs for big programs using LLVM clang

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-gcc, control-flow-graph

I want to create a software-generated control flow diagram for this code using LLVM CFG https://github.com/inmcm/Simon_Speck_Ciphers/blob/master/C/speck.c

But when I followed the instructions given on the LLVM webpage (https://www.programmersought.com/article/61364910575/), and typed the following command: `clang -S -emit-llvm simon.c -o g.ll`

Terminal shows this error message:

```
clang: error: -emit-llvm cannot be used when linking
```

I am new to this tool and Linux, can someone please help?

Comment: You have a typo, the `-S` should be capital.

Comment: I did capital -S in the terminal, but it gave the above error. Sorry, there was a typo in my initial post, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate the llvm IR and the CFG dot files for the above mentioned  `speck.c` file. The message `cannot be used when linking` appears only when you haven't passed any special flags for output like `-S`, `-c`, etc. so I'm guessing you have made some typo in the command.

You can try using `clang -save-temps speck.c` command, which would generate the bitcode (`.bc`) file for the LLVM IR, which can be used in any place where the `.ll` file is used.